# How to show array of DNN search result objects in html within a custom search results module

Tags: search, dotnetnuke

I currently have the following code within our custom Search Results Module to get DNN search results as well as results from our own system.

How can I show these Object results in HTML from C#?

Currently our search results module only retrieves products from our ERP system via ajax and displays them in a grid pattern. I now want to show page search results at the top of these Grid results from DNN itself, so these will be keywords on pages.

I was playing around with the following but I think I am not doing it correctly: searchResults.Results[0].Desciption?

I can't find examples

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a foreach function to achieve what I was trying to do:

```
txtSearchQueryString.Text = GetQuery;

                var query = new SearchQuery
                {
                    PageSize =  50,
                    PageIndex = (1 > 0 ? 1 : 1),
                    SortField = SortFields.Relevance,
                    SortDirection = SortDirections.Descending,
                    KeyWords = GetQuery,
                    PortalIds = new List<int> { PortalSettings.PortalId },
                    WildCardSearch = false,
                };

                TotalPageResults = "0";
                var searchResults = SearchController.Instance.ModuleSearch(query);

                if(searchResults != null)
                {
                    TotalPageResults = searchResults.TotalHits.ToString();
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine("<div class='page_results'><span class='page_results_text'>Page Results:</span></br>");
                    foreach(var result in searchResults.Results)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine($"</br><span><a href='{result.Url}' class='page_results_link'>{result.Title}</a></span></br><span class='page_result_description'>{result.Description}</span></br><span class='page_results_date_modified'>Updated:{result.DisplayModifiedTime}</span></br>");
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine("</div>");

                    DNNSearchResuls = sb.ToString(); 
                }
```